# SQL Server Express LocalDB: update a value if it begins with a certain digit

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb

We are currently storing a load of customer mobile numbers, however most of them are missing the leading 0.

How can I add a 0 in SQL to the front of all mobile numbers where the first digit equals 7?

Comment: What is the DBMS you're using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel localbd

Comment: @MarkRotteveel From poking around it appears that localdb runs on SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I posted the comment there was no mention of localdb (though even then, the specific version of localdb would be helpful).

Comment: Which version of SQL Server localdb are you using?

Comment: What is the data type of the column? A numeric column for example won't store a leading 0. Also, are you not concerned about the length of the number? If you're trying to update mobile numbers with country code 7, don't you want to ignore numbers with country code 72?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `LIKE` here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET mobile = '0' + mobile
WHERE mobile LIKE '7%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a concat statement

```
update table
set yourcolumn = CONCAT('0', yourcolumn)
where yourcolumn like '7%'
```